# Flatness of objects in a prestable $\infty$-category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy, flatness

I wonder what is the correct concept of flatness of objects in a prestable $\infty$-category with appropriate conditions?

The typical example is the following. Let $R$ be a connective $\mathbb E_1$-ring. Then we say that a connective right $R$-module $M$ is *flat* [Lurie's [Higher Algebra](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf), Def 7.2.2.10] if the right $\pi_0(R)$-module $\pi_0(M)$ is flat, and the canonical map $\pi_0(M)\otimes_{\pi_0(R)}\pi_n(R)\to\pi_n(M)$ is an isomorphism for every $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Lazard's theorem tells us that a connective right $R$-module $M$ is flat if and only if it can be written as a filtered colimit of finite free right $R$-modules. This generalizes to prestable $\infty$-categories generated by compact projective objects:

**Definition 1.** Let $\mathcal M_{\ge0}$ be a projectively generated prestable $\infty$-category. We say that an object $M\in\mathcal M_{\ge0}$ is *Lazard-flat* if it can be written as a filtered colimit of compact projective objects of $\mathcal M_{\ge0}$.

Another characterization is in terms of tensor products: a connective right $R$-module $M$ is flat if and only if the tensor product $\operatorname{LMod}_R\to\operatorname{Sp},N\mapsto M\otimes_RN$ carries the heart into the heart.

This should also generalize to certain prestable $\infty$-categories. The key observation is that $\operatorname{LMod}_R$ is the dual of $\operatorname{RMod}_R$, which leads to the following attempt:

**Definition 2.** Let $\mathcal M_{\ge0}$ be a dualizable Grothendieck prestable $\infty$-category. Let $\mathcal M^\heartsuit$ denote its heart. We say that an object $M\in\mathcal M_{\ge0}$ is *flat* if the composite functor $\mathcal M^\vee\xrightarrow{(-)\boxtimes M}\mathcal M^\vee\otimes\mathcal M\xrightarrow{\operatorname{ev}}\operatorname{Sp}$ carries $(\mathcal M^\heartsuit)^\vee$ to $\operatorname{Ab}=\operatorname{Sp}^\heartsuit$.

I wonder whether these concepts are studied and compared in the literature, or whether there are other flatness which could be compared with these two?

Comment: It seems like an interesting question to compare these two notions. I am not aware of anything in this direction in the literature.